# Load larger image on tap of small image with animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimage

I'm trying to load a large version of an image in the centre of the user's screen when then tap on a smaller version of the image that's already on my view.

Ideally I want to do this using an animation to get to the new image like a vertical flip.

Also if there's a way to make the background look greyed out like it's not the foreground then that would be even better.

Here's an image of what I'm after, I'm at work at the moment so haven't got access to the actual code / images.

I'm a new user so can't add pictures. Click here if you want to see what I'm thinking.
[Image](http://i46.tinypic.com/28bxtsj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I added the larger image on to begin with and set its alpha to 0, then added a gesture recognizer on the smaller image that animated the larger one and gradually changed its alpha to 1. The did the reverse on the large image. Don't know why I didn't think of that in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

There is an [KGmodal Example Exist in GitHUB](https://github.com/kgn/KGModal) hope that Might Help you.

You have to Change the content view and Add an `Imageview` Programatically (with required size ) in the content View.

Follow the below link: https://github.com/kgn/KGModal

For Fliping the image see the [tutorial iphone Flip Image.](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iphone-FlipImage.html)